# A sequence with a gap between consecutive terms tending to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request

Define sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ as follows:

Let $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 2$ and $b_0 = 0, b_1 = 3$.

For $n\ge2$, $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}^3 - a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}+1} $ and $b_n = \frac{b_{n-1}^3 - b_{n-2}}{b_{n-1}b_{n-2}+1} $.

Let $A = \{{A_i : A_i = a_n \ 
 \text{or}  \ A_i = b_n, n \ge 2, A_i < A_{i+1}, i \ge 1} \} $ i.e $A$ is a sequence of all distinct elements of sequences $a_n, b_n, n \ge 2$ arranged in ascending order.

It appears the gap between successive elements of $A$ tends to infinity i.e for any positive integer $c$, we can find a positive integer $k$ such that $A_{i+1}-A_i >c$ for all $i>k$.

More generally let $A$ be the sequence of all terms of sequences $a_{(m, n)}, n\ge 2; $ $a_{m,0} = 0, a_{m, 1}= m \ge 2$, $a_{m,n} = \frac{a_{n-1}^3 - a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}+1} $. It appears we can always find a positive integer $k$ for any positive integer $c$ such that the gap $A_{i+1} - A_i $ is larger than $c$ for all $i>k$.

How do I go about proving that indeed there exists a  positive integer $k$ such that for any $c$, $A_{i+1} - A_i  >c$ for all $i>k$ ?  Is there some literature on sequences that can help me answer this question.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @SV I would like to  prove that given a positive integer $c$, we can always find a positive integer $k$ such that $A_{i+1}- A_i > c$ for all $i>k$.

Comment: It's easy to show that the gap between the successive terms of each of the sequences that make up $A$ tends to infinity. However, it's difficult to show that the  sequence $A$, a combination of two or more sequences whose terms are arranged in ascending order also behaves as its constituent sequences.

Comment: The first seven terms of sequence $a_{2, n} $  include $0,2, 8, 30, 112, 418, 1560$ and the first five terms of sequence $a_{3, n} $ include $ 0, 3, 27, 240, 2133 $. If $ A $ is a combination of only these two sequences, then the first seven terms of sequence $A$ include $8, 27, 30, 112, 240, 418, 1560$. The gap between the second and third term of this sequence is $30-27=3$. It appears all other successive gaps are larger than $ 3 $